Compare means and effects in simple GAMs
I'm a random post-doc and I'm struggling with GAMs. I have pretty little stats support in my lab so I'm forced to search outside....
So I have these GAMs (mgcv in R) where the response variable is the absorption efficiency of a caterpillar (dimensionless, ∈ ]0,1[)  or the retention time (in days), for 8 separate chemical elements, which can be considered as a separate factorial variable. Both response variables depend on a third variable, say the ingestion rate. For each element and each response (absorption efficiency, retention time), I have fitted exactly one model with the predictor being this ingestion rate, resulting in 16 models (8×2).
The relationships are clearly not linear, so I've used gams. I would now like to compare the averages between, say, the absorption efficiencies of C and that of N, and compare the effect of this ingestion rate on these absorption efficiencies.
I'd like to get p-values that test the differences between the means, as well as the differences between the effects of ingestion rate for each pair of elements, and for uptake efficiency and retention time. So I thought I'd take the model predictions and run pairwise t-tests between the distribution of predicted values to test for differences between means. For the effect, I thought of doing the same thing on the first derivatives provided by gratia::derivatives() in R.
Although fairly intuitive, this way of testing may not be the right one, statistically speaking. Indeed, it seems to me that the i.i.d. hypothesis is not verified since the predicted values of the model, as well as the values of the derivatives, depend on the values in the neighbourhood.
I thought you might have some input on this.

This is a very general question with many components, so getting answers may be challenging. In the meantime, you may find this blog post useful: https://ecogambler.netlify.app/blog/interpreting-gams/#how-do-i-report-effects-from-gams-in-scientific-publications
